# How to remove '\x' from list =[ '\xbb', '\x02', '\x00', '\x11', '\xbe']

Tags: python, serial-port

I have some data from **Serial Port** as follows

```
list_input =[ '\xbb', '\x02', '\x00', '\x11', '\xbe', '\x04', '\x00', '\x0', '\x08', '\x3', '\xb2', '\xdd', '\xd9', '\x01', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\xc4', '\x1e']
```

I want to remove '\x' from each element and get output like,

```
list_output=[bb,02,00,22,be,04,00,08,dd]
```

if i do this `list_input =''.join(map(str, list_input))` 
i get this output " �" �4 3���@    �" i.e garbage value.

Please suggest any suitable solution.

Comment: That is the correct value of the bytes in your data. What exactly are you hoping to get?

Comment: `[hex(ord(x))[2:] for x in list_input]`?

Comment: `"\xbb"` is one character only it's the hex representation of the char having the *ASCII* code 187 (*0xbb*). You want the string representation of the hex digits?

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta : Your solution worked for me. I was trying from last 2 days. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strings `\xbb`, `\x02` ecc are **single** character strings. What you are seeing is the hex escape representation of them, since the ASCII character with code `2` is not a printable character.

It seems like you actually want the base-16 representation of the number represented by this characters, without the `x` prefix, hence you can us e`ord` to obtain the ASCII value and then `hex` to convert it into its hexadecimal representation:

```
>>> ord('\x02')
2
>>> ord('\xbb')
187
>>> hex(2)
'0x2'
>>> hex(187)
'0xbb'
```

If you don't want the `0x` prefix oyu can just use slicing to remove that part:

```
result = [hex(ord(x))[2:] for x in list_input]
```